# Best practices writing Espresso tests for a multi modular Android projects (MVI/MVVM)

Tags: kotlin, android-espresso

I am looking into **Espresso Framework** to adopt the best practices for writing tests for a multi modular Android projects (`MVI/MVVM`).

- Is it a good idea to cover/write all the Espresso tests inside the `app` module (or) it needs to be isolated specific to each modules?
- Is there any other best practices for `MVI/MVVM` based Android projects? if so, please comment and provide references if any

**Language used:** Kotlin

Answer (score 1):

I have recently been implementing espresso tests in the multi-modular project where I work. Through some research and help from senior developers, I think I will be able to guide you a bit in the proper direction.

1. For the first question, Yes, it's essential that all the tests related to a particular activity remain in their corresponding 'test' class. That keeps it modular and easy to debug. So, one should make a test class for a particular activity and that should be in the corresponding module that the 'activity' belongs.
2. All these test classes can then help you to build a 'TestSuite' which could be used to make a flow for testing the app's specific features. In a test suite, one needs to mention those classes that make that flow.
3. After all this research and as per knowledge, I guess, this approach is good enough for large projects as well since the app I am working on is really big.

Blocker :
In a multi-modular project, I am still not able to create the test suite since I am not able to import those test classes in the main app module. But this issue will be fixed very soon. I'll definitely update it here when I'll get the method to do so.

Please do comment, if I am doing something wrong. Suggestions are a warm welcome.